# iOS Simulator - Canot Allocate Memory to app

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios-simulator

I'm fairly new to iOS: I'm creating a simple application where I can add drawings on top of an image : and I can change the color I'm drawing with . . . .

After drawing for some time I get the following error on the iPad Simulator

```
CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 1478400 bytes for bitmap data
```

this is roughly 1.5MB . . . . how can this be an issue ? 
what am I doing wrong ?

My application lets me draw on top of a JPEG File, the Jpeg file itself is merely 111KB
I'm drawing inside a Single UIImageView so I don't think releasing the object is the issue- is it?

Any guidance is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get `ARC` support with `Objective-C`, so you're responsible for memory management when using frameworks that aren't written in `Objective-C`.  What you describe above can be an issue if you're creating many large objects (like a 1.5 MB bitmap context) and never releasing these objects.

You should familiarize yourself with the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127-SW1).  The gist is that if you invoke a function with the word `Copy` or `Create`, or you call `CFRetain` (or similar method) on a Core Foundation style object (i.e., `CGContextRef`), you "own" it, and it is your responsibility to at some point pair a call to `CFRelease` to relinquish your ownership.  If you don't, the objects stick around forever and you eventually run out of heap space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I figured out was it was all due to the fact that I was missing a line of code in my work :     `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`
which was missing from my drawing code

Comment: Also a memory leak of sorts.  Hopefully I set you down the right path at least.

Comment: indeed . . . . Thank you and thats why i've accepted your answer